# We are using HCL OneTest UI to do the Web Automation. Trying to read and write data through MS Excel, but not sure how to do this

Tags: uiautomation, web

Is there a way to integrate HCL OneTest UI to read from and write to MS Excel. I know apache poi libs provide the ability to do so though I am not sure how it will work with HCL OneTest UI.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache POI libraries would be right solution to it. In HCL OneTest UI - WebUI test, user can insert Java Custom code step and which can consume the any form of Java Code including read from and write to MS Excel sheets. 
To add a new Java Custom Code step in a Test, Open WebUI Test in the Editor and select the Test Name, do Right Click and select "Insert Java Custom Code" option.You also need to include APACHE POI dependencies to the buildpath of the project.